# Auto play next video without click next button with maximage 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this little customized [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsxrprf2/) using [maximage](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) and [cycle jquery plugins](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html). I wan't to ask is there any way to me to autoplay next video background without clicking next button, so the video background slider will be running automatically.

I try to put `$('#arrow_right').trigger('click');` inside below script without any luck

```
after: function(last,current){
    if(!$.browser.msie){
        if($(last).find('video').length > 0) $(last).find('video')[0].pause();
    }
}
```